# Quantile function in matlab

Tags: matlab, quantile

How does quantile function work in matlab?

for example:
x=[3;14;9;18;5;10;13;20;1]; and A=quantile(X,2), we get two results in A i.e 
A=[7;13.5].

Comment: Regarding the documentation of quantile() you should only get an answer of the same length as p, which in your case p=2 has the length 1. Are you sure p is only a scalar in your case?

Comment: Did you try typing `help quantile` on the MATLAB command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantile.html):

> Y = quantile(X,N) returns quantiles for N evenly spaced cumulative probabilities (1/(N + 1), 2/(N + 1), ..., N/(N + 1)) for integer N>1.

In your case, it returns quantiles for probabilities [1/3, 2/3], so two values.